# Event invocation via COM throwing access violation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, vb6, com-interop

I have a legacy VB6 application in which we're referencing a .NET DLL setup to be exposed to COM. In one of the methods in this .NET DLL, we need to block the thread while we wait for an event, and once we receive that event, we can return from the method. Currently I'm creating a `Task` object that performs the work that's done after we receive the event, then I subscribe to said event with this task, and finally I `WaitOne` on the `AutoResetEvent` I'm using to control the thread. I also set the task `ContinueWith` to `Set` the `AutoResetEvent`.

When I test this setup with a console app (written in .NET), I don't have a single issue. However, when I call this same method through VB6, *sometimes* it works, other times it doesn't, and will just hang indefinitely waiting for that event to fire.

I've been picking it apart using WinDbg, and I'm noticing on all the attempts that hang, an access violation is being thrown. I'm trying to figure out the source of this access violation currently, however it's right at the point in the .NET code where we invoke the event delegate if not null.

Here is a sample from WinDbg of this occurring:

> >>> Instantiated object
>
> >>> Starting events thread
>
> >>> Subscribing to OnCreateCtiConf
>
> >>> Waiting for task result.
>
> >>> Enqueued OnCreateCTIConf : No message
>
> (1e44.1c4c): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
>
> First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
>
> This exception may be expected and handled.
>
> eax=0a61e9d0 ebx=0a65bccc ecx=00000000 edx=0a7057a4 esi=0a61e9d0 edi=0caef804
>
> eip=091249a4 esp=0caef7e0 ebp=0caef810 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
>
> cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010202
>
> 091249a4 3909            cmp     dword ptr [ecx],ecx  ds:0023:00000000=????????

Here is the method we're calling that sometimes hangs:

```
public bool AgentLogin(string extension, string agentId, string password)
{
    _extension = extension;
    _agentId = agentId;
    _eventQueue = new Queue<AvayaEvent>();
    try
    {
        _phone = new CTISoftphone($"ext={extension},logFile={Settings.LogLocation}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        addEvent(new AvayaEvent(CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnError, $"{_wrapperLogPrefix} Unable to create CTISoftPhone. The error was: {ex.Message}"));
        return false;
    }

    _phone.PhoneEvent += new CTISoftphone.PhoneEventHandler((evnt, msg) =>
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($">>> Enqueued {evnt} : {(string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg) ? "No message" : msg)}");
        addEvent(new AvayaEvent(evnt, msg));
    });
    Trace.WriteLine(">>> Starting events thread");
    t_avayaEvents.Start();

    var are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    var task = new Task(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(">>> Calling LoginAgent");
            _phone.LoginAgent(agentId, password);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    });
    task.ContinueWith((t) => are.Set());

    var task_handler = new OnCreateCtiConfHandler(task.Start);

    Trace.WriteLine(">>> Subscribing to OnCreateCtiConf");
    OnCreateCtiConf += task_handler;
    Trace.WriteLine(">>> Waiting for task result.");
    are.WaitOne();
    Trace.WriteLine(">>> Unsubscribing from OnCreateCtiConf");
    OnCreateCtiConf -= task_handler;
     return true;
}
```

We initially thought the events were being missed before we could subscribe to the exposed `PhoneEvent`, hence the event queue loop thread. Basically we add the `AvayaEvent` to a `Queue<T>` and a separate thread processes these events. If there is a delegate, it fires and forgets, else, the event is requeued. For reference, we still had this overall issue before we implemented the event queue.

For COM interop, we've done a few things:

1. Interfaces have been created for the `Phone` object, and its events (separate interfaces for members and events)
2. `ComVisible(true)` has been set on anything we need to expose to COM
3. `DispId`s have been set on all members in each of these interfaces

Our main object, `Phone`, is decorated like so:

```
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IClickToDialEvents))]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IClickToDial))]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Phone : IClickToDial
{
    [...]
}
```

The interfaces referenced, `IClickToDial` and `IClickToDialEvents` are decorated like so:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IClickToDial
{
    [...]
}

[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IClickToDialEvents
{
    [...]
}
```

The events are members of the `Phone` class, below is a sample of what they look like:

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public delegate void OnCreateCtiConfHandler();

public event OnCreateCtiConfHandler OnCreateCtiConf;
```

The process events loop looks like:

```
private void processEventsInQueue()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (_eventQueue?.Count > 0)
        {
            var evnt = getNextEvent();
            Trace.WriteLine($">>> Dequeued {evnt.Type}");
            switch (evnt.Type)
            {
                case CTISoftphone.CTIEvent.OnCreateCtiConf:
                    if (OnCreateCtiConf != null)
                        OnCreateCtiConf();
                    else
                        addEvent(evnt);
                    break;
                [...]
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

And finally, the `addEvent` and `getNextEvent` methods look like:

```
private AvayaEvent getNextEvent()
{
    lock (this)
        return _eventQueue.Dequeue();
}
private void addEvent(AvayaEvent evnt)
{
    lock (this)
    {
        try
        {
            _eventQueue.Enqueue(evnt);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            //swallow the nullrefexception since we null out _eventQueue when we dont want to queue anything
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, when we register this DLL with COM, we're using the following RegAsm command: `.\RegAsm.exe 'C:\Program Files\Avaya\ClickToDial\<OurDll>.dll' /codebase /tlb` and then we reference the generated tlb file in our VB6 application.

Like I said, sometimes this works fine and we return from the AgentLogin method with no issues. Othertimes, we hang indefinitely, and I always see the access violation on these hangs. I'd say the split is about 50/50.

This is the first COM interop project I've worked on so I'm probably missing something obvious, but this is driving me crazy! If more information/clarification is needed, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but I think that you can block the thread without requiring an AutoReset event, by calling Task.Wait().  Maybe this helps?

Comment: Also I would strongly recommend adding an AutoResetEvent to your queue processing loop, so that you can sleep the processing thread while awaiting for something to be queued (the enqueue operation sets the event);  whithout the event, you will peg one of your CPU cores on a loop that is furiously querying the queue count).

Comment: So I've been digging around today, and it looks like the access violation might have lead me down the wrong path. I removed the queueing system implemented in the code above and am just letting the events fire if the handler isn't null. I also added additional logging during this, and in doing so, found out that we somehow have multiple versions of this COM object live at the same time! I'm now thinking we aren't releasing our COM object when we close the VB6 app, so I'm trying to figure out how to do that. I cut my teeth on .NET, COM is a whole new world!